# Can anyone tell me the name of this function?

Tags: analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, statistical-mechanics

So recently I came across this function (it was in the context of Bose-Einstein condensation in Statistical Mechanics):

$F_\nu (\xi) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu)}\int_0^\infty{\frac{x^{\nu-1}}{e^x/\xi -1}dx}$

Where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. It seems to resemble closely the integral form of the Riemann Zeta function if not for the $1/\xi$ (inverse fugacity $e^{\beta\mu}\in(0,1]$) in the integral. I have been looking for ages for it but I cannot seem to find any trace so I thought I'd ask about it here

Furthermore I have in my notes that

$F_\nu(\xi)=\sum_k{\frac{\xi^k}{k^\nu}}$ for $\nu=5/2$

Is this the case for all $\nu$ where the standard Riemann Zeta function would be defined as a generalised harmonic series? Or is it some kind of an approximation for this particular value of $\nu$?

Comment: You may want to look at [*polylogarithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: This is an integral repesentation of the polylogarithm, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12.E11
$$\mathrm{Li}_{s}\left(z\right)=\frac{z}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-z}\mathrm{d}x$$ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Integral_representations